# Talend date and time combine

Tags: date, time, concatenation, talend, unparseable

I combine two columns; date and time. When I pass the date and time hot coded it works fine but when I pass it through a column it throws the error:

> Unparseable date: "05/05/1992"

I already tried this:

```
MaterialCodeCSV.xdate == null ? 
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) : 
TalendDate.parseDateLocale("yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss",MaterialCodeCSV.xdate.toString() +  MaterialCodeCSV.xtime.toString(),"EN");
```

Java code in Talend:

[image: Java code in Talend]

Comment: Does all the date in the column "MaterialCodeCSV.xtime" have the same format "01/01/2000" ? And what is the type of the column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date handling can be a bit tricky if using wrong data types. I assume you want to fill a field which is a `Date`. There are several errors with this way:

```
MaterialCodeCSV.xdate == null ? 
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) : 
TalendDate.parseDateLocale("yyyy/mm/dd H:mm:ss",MaterialCodeCSV.xdate.toString()+ MaterialCodeCSV.xtime.toString(),"EN");
```

- If `MaterialCodeCSV.xdate == null` you create a date and parse it again instantly? That seems unneccessary complex and inefficient. Change this to `TalendDate.getCurrentDate()`
- Then if `xdate` is not null, you just concat `xdate` and `xtime`, use `toString()` and try to parse this. Again, this seems unneccesary complex. If I just assume now and `xdate` and `xtime` are already `Date` fields, you could write it as this: `MaterialCodeCSV.xdate + MaterialCodeCSV.xtime`.
- If both are `String` fields, you *have* to make sure that `xdate` is formatted `yyyy/MM/dd` and `xtime` is `HH:mm:ss`. Then you could exclude `.toString()`
- Also, if both are `String` fields, you have to add an additional space: `MaterialCodeCSV.xdate + ' ' + MaterialCodeCSV.xtime`
- Additionally, in the first case you parse with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. In the second case you parse with `yyyy/mm/dd H:mm:ss`. This reads "year/minute/day". Also there is only one hour digit, not allowing anything after 9:59:59 o'clock to be parsed. Correctly you should use `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`.

So to conclude it should look like this (if I assume correctly and you are using correctly formatted `String` fields for `xdate` and `xtime`):

```
MaterialCodeCSV.xdate == null ? 
TalendDate.getCurrentDate() : 
TalendDate.parseDateLocale("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", MaterialCodeCSV.xdate + ' ' + MaterialCodeCSV.xtime,"EN");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your brief explanation its very helpful